# Full width element exceeding parent's width - but with a max-width

Tags: html, css

I using this setup to make hero elements exceed to full page width:
Html:

```css
main {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor...</p>
    <figure class="full-width">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/hero.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>Some text.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor...</p>
</main>
```

But I would like to set a max-width, so if the screen is more than, say, 2000px, then stop making the "full-width" element full width, but instead just 2000px wide and centered (and still exceeding the parent element's width). How can I achieve this?

I tried with:

```
@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  .full-width {
    max-width: 2000px;
  }
}
```

but it just pushed the element to one side.

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/d6t9s0nc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happnes because of margines. You can just use,

```
   .full-width{
    width: 100%,
    margin: 0px
    }
```

And also use

```
Padding : 0px
```

In parent if needed.

Comment: This is spot on! Thank you very much.
I only had to add a few more lines more to overwrite the initial styling, like this:

`.full-width {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: auto;
   right: auto;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: flex` property in order to handle the alignment:

```
main {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  .full-width {
       max-width: 2000px;
  }
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I just adapted the answer, please try these updated styles.